# How to change Window's RTL text cursor icon?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is it possible to change the text cursor icons in Windows 10?

Specifically, I want to change the RTL text cursor icon because it resembles the LTR icon too much, making it difficult to notice if you are in RTL or LTR mode.

LTR text cursor:

[image: LTR text cursor]

RTL text cursor:

[image: RTL text cursor]